# Right Click in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

How to set contectmenu in silverlight 4.0

My code is :

```
  <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
       <toolkit:ContextMenu>
               <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Edit"/>
      </toolkit:ContextMenu>
 </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
```

But i have error like this.

Attachable property contextmenu not found

Comment: Do you added the necessary assembly references to your project and defined the namspace in your xaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add following line this in xaml.

```
 xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
```

You also have to give dll following referance

```
 System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll
 System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit.dll
 System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll
```